# What is the driving Voltage?

Tags: signal-analysis, acoustics, beamforming, sensor, psychoacoustics

While I was looking into ultrasonic transducer in order to transmit and receive a beam, I came across specification of a transducer stating driving voltage as 20Vrms. I am not sure what actually does it mean and where is the application of driving voltage in transducer(I mean is it used at transmitting or receiving end? or what is its function?). I wonder what parameters of the transducer will be affected due to application of driving voltage?
Below is the specification of the transducer.[image]

Comment: [Spec sheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1686089.pdf) for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20Vrms is the maximum voltage you can apply across the transmitting transducer without the risk of immediately damaging it.

The amplitude of sound it produces is determined by the driving voltage. The transmitter is characterized at 10Vrms, so about 28Vp-p assuming a sine wave, probably where you would prefer to use it for reliability and long life.

Comment: thank you @spehro

Comment: Just an addition...can I provide  the driving voltage using external dc power supply to the transducer..Or will I need AC to drive it?

Comment: It needs AC, preferably with no DC content, and sinusoidal.